# CSS How to set height of an element according to its number of children

Tags: html, css

I using with transition for creating an accordion animation

```
.ac-container input:not(:checked) ~ article.ac-small{
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0px!important;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        transition:height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
```

the above code refer to a situation when the section is closed
But when I want to open this section I need to set it an height but I dont know what is the exact height because it render according to the array length it contains.

I find a way to do so using a js code...

```
  $('.ac-container .onCallUsersSection input:checked ~ article.ac-small').css({'height' : $ctrl.lstOnCallUsers.length * 73 + 'px', 'transition': 'height 0.3s ease-in-out'});
```

How can I do it in css and not in js?

Comment: I think there is no way because css is not able to calculate like this. Maybe you can change your layout so you dont have to set a specific height.

Comment: You could possibly set .ac-small to have overflow-y: scroll. This will allow you to insert as many elements inside of ac-small and still be able to see all of them. You just make .ac-small a set height. There will be a way to do what you are doing, but I think you will need to play with the min-height/max-height properties.

Comment: It's cases like this where it becomes even more advantageous to include a live example.

Comment: For zero lengths you should omit the unit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using max-height: 0px!important; and    max-height: 230px;

```
.ac-container input:not(:checked) ~ article.ac-small{
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0px!important;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        transition:max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
        transition: max-height .3s ease-in-out;
        max-height: 230px;
    }
```